# Python communicate with a subprocess

Tags: python, streaming, subprocess, producer-consumer

I have a subprocess which is constantly producing data, but most of the data I'm not interested in.  However occasionally, at random times, I need to grab a sample of the output - the thing is I need to read it at well defined boundaries.  For example, let's assume the process produces a constant 100 bytes per second and useful information comes in chunks of 100 bytes.  After it has been running for 4 seconds, I ask to see 100 bytes of output, then I would be interested in bytes 400-499 inclusive.  But if I ask at 4.1 seconds, I don't want to intercept and get bytes 410-509, I need to wait and see bytes 500-599.  Otherwise, the process should be happily streaming its output to `/dev/null` and **I don't want to ever block the output stream**.  My friend fred might also ask for 100 bytes at, say, 4.6 seconds, so I also need to tee off that stuff and make the data available to multiple consumers for reading.

Is there an existing design pattern for this kind of thing?  How can I implement it with python subprocess, and ensure that communication with the subprocess is non-blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to constantly read from the given stdout, in chunks of 100 bytes. Then you have a list of consumers - which might just be implemented as functions taking strings/bytestrings (depending on if you are on 2.x or 3.x). Each chunk is sent to every consumer and then discarded.

Something like this:

```
def f_a(s): pass
def f_b(s): pass

consumers = [f_a, f_b]

while True:
    chunk = process.stdout.read(100)
    if chunk == '': break # or something like that
    for c in consumers: c(chunk)
```

If you run this in a thread, you can modify the consumers as you want/need.

But you should take care that the consumers don't block - otherwise your loop blocks. That's no problem, if it doesn't last too long, because the OS gives you a quite large buffer between your subprocess and you. But it is not infinite. So there might be a need to add some buffering, either per consumer or in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Well I am new to python, but it seems proc.communicate or proc.stdout.readline/readlines waits till the process has completed.

As per my knowledge, you can implement a rotational logging and redirect output to a file, then using subprocess you can fire tailf -n XX logfile, in a loop until the program ends, and print the output whenever there is a request from the user end.

Answer (score -1):

```
import subprocess
subProc= subprocess.Popen(['tail','/dev/random'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subProc.stdout[400:499] ?
```

or

```
subProc.stdout.seek(400).read(100)
```

if those doesn't work. try:

```
var = subProc.stdout
var[400:499]
```

Also to get proper output from your subprocess you need to flush() once in a while with Python3.X if i'm not mistaken:
sys.stdout.flush()

For some wierd reason i don't have any access to any of my unix environments so i can't really test the code, but in theory this should do what you're asking.

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but it's obvious why: neither suggestions are even working.